# MYSQL - update a table column result of a query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in my database which three columns of data:

```
1) The clubname;
2) The teamname;
3) The pouleid;
```

All clubs have more than 1 team. Each team has 2 pouleid's (an indoor and an outdoor id).

I want to loop through the combination of club-team and find the corresponding pouleid's. Then I want to set the lower pouleid to "outdoor" and the higher pouleid to "indoor" in another column of this table.

I can find the results from a specific club/team-combination with a query LIKE

Indoor:

```
"SELECT pouleid FROM Stand WHERE clubnaam = 'ZKC' AND clubteam = 'A1' LIMIT 0,1"
```

Outdoor:

```
"SELECT pouleid FROM Stand WHERE clubnaam = 'ZKC' AND clubteam = 'A1' LIMIT 1,1"
```

But how can I loop through the whole table and find the matching club/team-combination and than update the column with indoor or outdoor? Is that possible in MySql?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I dont think you can solve this only by using SQL...
You can easily do this by using any programing language like php or asp. Get all Unique values, and use them
one at a time to solve your problem.